# instantiated using the ScriptableObject.CreateInstance

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to create a button and multiple Sliders that update based each others values. Since every button and set of sliders is highly related I tried to call one method that would update the set, therefore I call one Update method for `GenerateItem`, rather than calling Update on each Object and making them reference each other.

**Why am I getting the error above, and what is the "Unity" way to solve this? My program will likely have a lot of these sliders and Buttons so I would rather not code them all by hand.**

> GenerateItem must be instantiated using the ScriptableObject.CreateInstance method instead of new GenerateItem

```c#
void Start () {

    Button a = ((GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton)).GetComponent<Button>();
    Slider b = ((GameObject)Instantiate(prefabCreationSlider)).GetComponent<Slider>();
    Slider c = ((GameObject)Instantiate(prefabCapacitySlider)).GetComponent<Slider>();
    Text d = ((GameObject)Instantiate(prefabText)).GetComponent<Text>();
    items.Add(new GenerateItem("OxyGen", 0.5f, 50f,a,c,b,d));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    items.ForEach(a => a.BtnUpdate());
}
```

I tried:

```c#
GenerateItem o= ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(GenerateItem);
```

but couldn't figure out how to set the properties of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the code of the ScriptableObjects.

But you either have to use `CreateInstance(Type)` which returns a `ScriptableObject` and cast the created instance to your type:

```c#
GenerateItem o = (GenerateItem) ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(typeof(GenerateItem));
```

Or simply use the typed version `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Type>()` which returns a `Type` and therefore doesn't require the typecast (I prefer this one)

```c#
GenerateItem o = ScriptableObject.CreateInstace<GenerateItem>();
```

Than you can set the properties as usual

```c#
 o.<some property> = <some value>;
```

Note that the properties/fields ofcourse have to be public for this solution.

---

Alternatively have some kind of

```c#
public void SetValues(string name, float value1, float value2, Button button, Slider slider1, Slider slider2, Text text)
{
    // Apply values

    <some property> = <some value>
    /* ... */
}
```

method inside of the ScriptableObjects so you can simply call

```c#
o.SetValues("OxyGen", 0.5f, 50f, a, c, b, d);
```

---

Another alternative (and I personaly like this one most) - Factory pattern

Only allow setting of the values on instantiation and protect them against later direct changes. Have a method in `GenerationItem` that takes completely care of the instantiation and setting the values

```c#
public static GenerateItem CreateInstance(string name, float value1, float value2, Button button, Slider slider1, Slider slider2, Text text)
{
    // Let the method itself take care of the Instantiated
    // You don't need "ScriptableObject." since this class inherits from it
    GenerateItem o = CreateInstance<GenerateItem>();

    // Then directly set the values
    o.<some property> = <some value>;

    /* .... */

    return o;
}
```

So later in your class you just have to call

```c#
var o = GenerateItem.CreateInstance("OxyGen", 0.5f, 50f, a, c, b, d);
```

This makes sure values cannot be changed afterwards that easy. Depends on your needs.